# Braintree Payment gateway : paymentMethodNonceReceived unable to stop submitting form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, braintree

Here is my braintree javascript code.

```
braintree.setup("<?=$clientToken?>", "custom", {
    id: "checkout_prem",
    paymentMethodNonceReceived: function (event, nonce) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

After i click on submit button it will submit the form that  i don't want to.

Can anybody help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

On the click callback of your form pass in the event and use the event.preventDefault();

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 1):

use **onPaymentMethodReceived**  instead of **paymentMethodNonceReceived**
Then It will works:

Check this link for **more information**:
 [Braintree - paymentMethodNonceReceived not being invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068003/braintree-paymentmethodnoncereceived-not-being-invoked/31204031#31204031)

Thanks

http://www.web-technology-experts-notes.in